# Використання слова "наразі" в діловій документації

Tags: вживання-слів, стилістика

Підкажіть, чи можна в діловій документації, а саме під час протоколюванні наради вживати слово *"наразі"*.

Доповідачі часто використовують його у своїх виступах. Але коли я почала шукати, то натрапила на таку інформацію  у СЛОВОПЕДІЇ

> *На разі* (вислів польський, до речі, його треба окремо писати) у перекладі українською означає *“поки що”*, а не *“зараз”*, як вважають деякі автори газетних публікацій, теле- і радіопередач.

І тепер не знаю, як має бути правильно.

Answer (score 3):

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/narazi)

> ***НАРА́ЗІ,*** *присл., діал*. Поки що, зараз. *Всміхнувся [Леон] силуваним сміхом, не знаючи наразі, на яку відповідь здобутися* (Іван
>   Франко, V, 1951, 330); — *Наразі пані мусить ще якийсь час
>   відпочивати, — мовив він, запинаючись* (Ярослав Галан, Гори.., 1956,
>   19); — *Наразі піду до міста* (Семен Журахович, Бук. повість, 1959,
>   70).

[Експрес-урок від Олександра Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QL5iy84nEfA)

Варто пам'ятати слово **"наразі"** пишеться разом. Оскільки слово ***"наразі"*** діалектне використовувати його при протоколюванні наради не можна, краще написати слово **"зараз"** або **"поки що"**.

Із сайту ["Ділова мова"](https://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=10&tdmua=%C4%B3%E0%EB%E5%EA%F2%ED%E0-%EB%E5%EA%F1%E8%EA%E0)

> У сучасній літературній мові діалектна лексика зустрічається дуже
>   рідко. І зовсім не використовується в діловому мовленні, науковому та
>   публіцистичному стилях.

Comment: Не відповідає на запитання «чи можна в діловій документації» (але мінус не ставив, бо інформація корисна).

Comment: Але ж СУМ-11 стверджує, що воно діалектне. Чи можна діалектні слова вживати в діловій документації? Чи якісь новіші джерела стверджують, що воно вже вийшло за межі діалектної лексики?

Comment: Однак є підстави вважати, що слово «нара́зі» могло вийти за межі суто діалектної лексики. За даними [linguisto.eu](http://linguisto.eu/freq/наразі) вживання «наразі» у порівнянні з 1990-ми роками виросло принаймні на порядок; вживання слова «наразі» у прикладах [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl) збільшилося порівняно з СУМ-11 («вкладення¹», «донор»); на сайтах *.gov.ua «наразі» вживається понад 600 разів (rada >500). У словнику [ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53405/913997.html) і [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) «наразі» вже не має примітки «діал.».

Comment: (Вибачте, що ненавмисне схиляю Вашу відповідь то в один бік, то в інший, просто початкова версія Вашої відповіді, на мою думку, не відповідала до кінця на поставлене запитання.)

Comment: @Sasha на Вашу думку, яка має бути правильна відповідь? Я так зрозуміла з Ваших коментарів,  можемо вживати, але точного підтвердження цьому поки що немає.

Comment: Ну, мені здається саме так.

Comment: @Sasha можливо, краще не вживати, почекати підтвердження?

Comment: Ну, якщо Ваша думка така, то тоді логічно залишити Вашу відповідь у такому стані, як вона є. (Я тоді окремою відповіддю напишу, що, ймовірно, все йде до визнання цього слова, хоч точних підтверджень і нема.) (Я просто думав, що Ви чогось не врахували, але якщо це Ваша думка — то що ж, я не можу «змусити» думати по-іншому, лише «плюс» поставлю за закінчену відповідь.) (А, і ще одне: я б змінив «краще написати слово „зараз“» на «краще написати „зараз“ або „поки що“» — бо ж «наразі» має два значення, то так логічніше, по-моєму.)

Comment: @Sasha так, я вважаю, що краще почекати поки будуть підтвердження. Та у відповіді обов'язково додам "поки що".

Answer (score 0):

### **Наразі** - станом речей на зараз, на цей момент.

---

**Вставні слова**, особливо на початку речення або абзацу, цілком виправдана загально поширена техніка, властива **усному діловому мовленню**.

Та слід пам'ятати, що **документарна ділова мова** вимагає насамперед точності і достовірності інформації. Тому у Звіті чи Meeting report-е краще записати "станом на момент доповіді" або "станом на [дата] [час]".

> [**Прислівники часу**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)
>
> Характеризують дію за часовими відношеннями і відповідають на питання:
> **коли?**, **відколи?**, **як довго?**, **доки?** (*тепер*, *колись*, *віддавна*,
> *щороку*, *завжди*, *учора*, *понині*, *одвіку*).

[image]
[image]

[ДУМ](http://kk.nau.edu.ua/article/280)

---

**Особливості офіційно-ділового стилю української мови**

> Офіційно-діловий стиль задовольняє потреби суспільства в ділових,
> юридично-правових, виробничо-економічних і дипломатичних стосунках, вживається в ділових паперах – державних і приватних документах.
>
> **Основна функція** – повідомлення фактів державного і приватного
> значення. Загальні особливості стилю : офіційність, точність,
> конкретність змісту, чіткість, стислість, логічна послідовність,
> однозначність формулювань, стандартизація. Офіційно-діловий стиль
> вживається в писемній (рідше усній) формі; тип мовлення – розповідь,
> опис.
>
> **Лексичні особливості**: нейтральна лексика, професійні слова
> (формули- кліше),канцелярські штампи й шаблони. **У синтаксисі**
> офіційно-ділового стилю використовуються прості речення, поширені
> однорідними членами речення, вставними і вставленими конструкціями;
> вживаються безособові і наказові усталені конструкції, складнопідрядні
> речення з підрядними з’ясувальними , причини, умови, наслідку.
>
> [ДІЛОВА УКРАЇНСЬКА МОВА](https://dut.edu.ua/uploads/l_123_52036140.pdf)

**Основною одиницею офіційно-ділового стилю є документ**

> **Документ** – це засіб фіксації певним чином на спеціальному матеріалі інформації про факти, події, явища об'єктивної дійсності та
> розумової діяльності людини. Це матеріальний об'єкт, оформлений у
> заведеному порядку, який характеризується встановленою законодавством
> юридичною силою – властивістю, наданою йому чинним законодавством, яка
> є підставою для розв’язання правових питань, здійснення правового
> регулювання й виконання управлінських функцій.
>
> [ДІЛОВА УКРАЇНСЬКА МОВА](https://er.nau.edu.ua/bitstream/NAU/53320/5/10_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87.%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1.%20%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%9C.pdf)

[image]

[ДУМ - навчальний посібник](https://metod.suitt.edu.ua/download/290)

[Українське ділове мовлення](https://www.dilovamova.com)